# Python code gives IndexError despite giving ouput

Tags: python-3.x, index-error

I get an `IndexError` in python code.

This is the code :

```py
n = int(input())  
cardp_1 = [input() for i in range(n)]
warcount=0
m = int(input())  
cardp_2 = [input() for j in range(m)]
while cardp_1 != [] or cardp_2 != []:
    # print(cardp_1[0],cardp_2[0])
    c1 = cardp_1[0]
    c2 = cardp_2[0]
    res = stronger(c1, c2)
    if res == 1:
        cardp_1.remove(c1)
        cardp_2.remove(c2)
        cardp_1.append(c1)
        cardp_1.append(c2)
    elif res == 2:
        cardp_1.remove(c1)
        cardp_2.remove(c2)
        cardp_2.append(c1)
        cardp_2.append(c2)
if cardp_2 == []:
    print('2', warcount)
else:
    print('1', warcount)
```

The program should run just fine, instead, it is giving `IndexError` :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:/Users/risha/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/cards_war.py", line 9, in
<module>
    c2 = cardp_2[0] IndexError: list index out of range
```

The strange part is, I tried printing the values of `c1` and `c2` within the while-loop, and it gets printed for every iteration.

Comment: Can you provide example input that exhibits this behavior?  And the definition of `stronger`?

Comment: *The program should run just fine* - once all programs ran just fine. Until one day god said "Let there be bugs!", and then this site was created.... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop:

```
while cardp_1 != [] or cardp_2 != []:
```

says to keep iterating so long as *either* array is not empty, but then the first thing you do it take the first element from *both*.  If one array is empty, you will hit the very error you describe.

Comment: Yup. That solved it. It had to be 'and' instead of 'or'. Thanks Scott